# How do I create a shopping cart that accepts Bitcoin?

Tags: shopping-cart-interface

I need to start a website to sell and buy goods with Bitcoin. Then I need to know how to add an shopping cart system for it. Are there any CMS plugins or modules for Joomla, Drupal, or another? Or can you tell me how to add a shopping cart system for a PHP based website without any modules?

Comment: Do you mean Bitcoin (BTC/XBT) or BlackCoin ([BC](http://www.blackcoin.co/))?

Comment: I have no experience with it, but a quick Google (bitcoin shopping cart interface) yielded a pretty good (I think) list of open-source interfaces, which should be usefull. It is from [BitPay](https://bitpay.com/bitcoin-for-ecommerce)

Comment: The list of related questions (look to the right ---->) contains several that look relevant.

Answer (score -2):

I have same needs, and i found Stripe that accepts bitcoins payment similar like paypal do, then i planned too to use CMSs and i found a solid plugin for opencart on GitHub.
Simply googling i found alot of results, the bitcoin shopping cart plugins are around .. :D
I Also Found interesting bitcoinpay.com,
I can use Api to accept Bitcoin and send to a bitcoin address
...
 even if i not understood if i can operate as Anonymous or i have to link a bank account.
(Obviously i wannot)

The most for all is to find a way to collect bitcoins without to be forced to link a  Bank account.
Tms

Comment: -1 This answer would be much more useful if it linked the mentioned search results and explained how Stripe and BitcoinPay address the question of the asker.